# Workaround for using NOWAIT and SKIP LOCKED clause in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, jooq

I'm using Jooq for my DB transaction management. I found that the `NOWAIT` and `SKIP LOCKED` clauses are supported only in the later versions of MySQL. In the MYSQL version I'm using does not support them. So, in JooQ, is there a workaround for this to work? Where one thread doesn't wait for a locked entity and continues processing other entities without changing the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` DB configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKIP LOCKED` would be hard to emulate, but it makes perfect sense to emulate `WAIT n` or `NOWAIT` using the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` session variable. We're going to do that already for PostgreSQL in jOOQ 3.15, so why not do it for older versions of MySQL as well:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11243 (PostgreSQL)
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11543 (MariaDB, MySQL)

This will be made available in jOOQ 3.15

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Any thoughts on when this feature will be available for open source version?

Comment: @Picco: Implementing this now, 3.15 will be released these days. I didn't realise that newer versions of MySQL don't support a `WAIT n` syntax yet. This means that the emulation will be available also in the jOOQ Open Source Edition until MySQL supports `WAIT n`.